# Stop asynctask from other activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I creating an app using asynctask to download file from server. It has several activities. I start one asynctask from activity A and I want stop it from activity B. How can I archieve it ???

Comment: do you have used sharedprefrence before . try using it. it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to call a previous activity's public methods by using typecasting of the getParentActivity() method on your activity B :

```
((PreviousActivity)getParentActivity()).somePublicMethod();
```

This only works if you opened Activity B from Activity A. If you want to be able to call that method from all activities, try creating a static class and save an instance of Activity A. This way, wherever you are on the app, the method can be called. Be also wary of null values when doing this.

This is the sample of the static class.

```
public static class Constants{
   public static ActivityA activityAInstance;
}
```

When you open ActivityA (`onCreate` method) save it's instance:

```
Constants.activityAInstance = ActivityA.this;
```

This part saves the instance of ActivityA to your static class. So whereEver you are on the app, you can access that instance and call it's public methods:

e.g. the app is on ActivityZ all you have to do is import that static class and call ActivityA instance:

```
Constants.activityAInstance.somePublicMethodToStopTheAsyncTask();
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried to store asynctask to static variable. but sometime it returns null value. I want find a better solution for this.

Comment: No, not the async task but the instance of Activity A. Create a separate static class to store that instance. then call it 's public methods anywhere on the app.

Comment: it's not one asynctask. It has many asynctasks in listview to display download file from server

Comment: Can you post your code for displaying the listview including the asynctask. The null values cant be avoided for listviews recycles each row and many other stuff's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , you can set a boolean flag in activity A ,and when you run the asynctask , you should check this flag ever time,if you want to stop ,you just change the flag , so you could change this flag in activity B to stop the asynctask.

you should try this.

Comment: it's not one asynctask. It has many asynctasks in listview to display download file from server

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use LocalBroadcastIntent to send a message from activity B to activity A. In method receiver of A, you can call `Asynctask.cancel(true)`. And you should place
 `if(isCanceled()){ 
 break;
}`
in your asynctask's loop to stop the task when you call `Asynctask.cancel(true)`.